# How to convert Integer value into String value in flutter(dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

in my project, I needed one functionality that, they convert integer numbers into a string value,
example:-
if I  enter text field value is 200

so after the button click, I need to convert this integer value(**200**) into the English name of this integer value.
that is **two hundred**
So after the button click, I need this text **two hundred** if the user fills integer value into the text field.
is there any package or dart method available for this task?

Answer (score 0):

I use this package for this purpose:

https://pub.dev/packages/number_to_character

Comment: this is working at some limit. because this package work at a limit of a quintillion.see that
https://github.com/makri-aymen/number_to_character/blob/main/lib/number_mappings.dart